# List not passing to the Recycler Adapter from Activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList to my recycler adapter class. I've successfully implemented 2 other recycler views in my code but in this case the array list equal to null is being passed. Here is the code for my activity.

```
public class PlacedOrders extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar tb;
private User u;
private ArrayList<OrderModel> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference ordersReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_placed_orders);

    tb = findViewById(R.id.customToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    u = i.getParcelableExtra("USER_DATA");

    ordersReference = root.child("Orders").child(u.getUserId());
    setRecyclerView();
}

public void setRecyclerView(){

    ordersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                OrderModel om = (ds.getValue(OrderModel.class));
                orderList.add(om);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_storeOrders_parent);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    PlacedOrderParentAdapter placedOrderParentAdapter = new PlacedOrderParentAdapter(this, orderList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(placedOrderParentAdapter);

    }
}
```

I've used the debugger to check the for loop, the array is successfully populated with items in the loop but as soon as the loop ends, it's size drops to zero. 
Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add. When I add an OrderModel object manually to the ArrayList without using the datasnapshot loop. The recycler view works fine

Answer (score 1):

Before set your adapter and you can try this:

```
public void setRecyclerView(){

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_storeOrders_parent);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
PlacedOrderParentAdapter placedOrderParentAdapter = new PlacedOrderParentAdapter(this, orderList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(placedOrderParentAdapter);

ordersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            OrderModel om = (ds.getValue(OrderModel.class));
            orderList.add(om);
        }
       placedOrderParentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

}
```

Call **notifyDataSetChanged()** method after populated the orderList

Answer (score 0):

That's because `recyclerview.setAdapter` is called before the data is retrieved from the database and `onDataChange` method is called.
The best way in my point of view to handle this case is to create a method in ur adapter class to take new items and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in it after adding the item to load the new changes in your list

In your adapter class:

```java
public void addItem(OrderModel order){
   myorderlist.addItem(order);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and your code becomes like that

```java
public void setRecyclerView(){

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_storeOrders_parent);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
PlacedOrderParentAdapter placedOrderParentAdapter = new PlacedOrderParentAdapter(this, orderList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(placedOrderParentAdapter);

ordersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            OrderModel om = (ds.getValue(OrderModel.class));
            placedOrderParentAdapter.addItem(om);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the `onDataChange()` call back takes some time before executing:

What you can do is this:

**Do you see these 2 lines in your `setRecyclerView()` method:**

```
PlacedOrderParentAdapter placedOrderParentAdapter = new PlacedOrderParentAdapter(this, orderList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(placedOrderParentAdapter);
```

**Move them directly under the for loop in `onDataChange()`:**

```
...........
ordersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            OrderModel om = (ds.getValue(OrderModel.class));
            orderList.add(om);
        }
     //here
     PlacedOrderParentAdapter placedOrderParentAdapter = newPlacedOrderParentAdapter(this, orderList);
     recyclerView.setAdapter(placedOrderParentAdapter);
    }
    ..........
    ..........
```